# range hood with an offset

Tags: kitchens, hood, range

We have an old and rusty range hood in our kitchen that needs to be replaced. It is 42" wide (over a 31" cooktop).

The problem is that the vent opening is not at the center of the hood (see picture). All we could find are standard hoods where the duct opening must be at the center ([here](http://www.ajmadison.com/b.php/Standard+Hood%3BHood%3BInternal%3BUnder+Cabinet%3BDucted%3BWidth%3A+42%22+-+42.9%22%3BRange+Hoods/N~32+345+4294960093+4294964305+1175+4294960155+4294961930) for example).

Does anyone know a hood model that looks like this? or that can be easily modified to look like this? Or is a non-ducted hood our only chance?

Thanks

[image: Hood offset]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never seen one like this - BUT have installed many a hood in cabinets where the vent did not end up exiting the center of the cabinet.  a combination of adjustable elbows will offset the vent if you have at least 15" height in the cabinet.  As a last resort flexible aluminum duct could be used but only if you have no other options.

Comment: Flexible alu ducts are most commonly seen in my area of living. Kitchen shelves (and range hood pre-installed inside) are placed independently and there is always like 10-30cm difference. Upvoted.

Comment: The reason I use the flexible ducts only as a last resort is due to the failure rate compared to rigid duct.  That and their rough surface area which slows air flow and collects grease faster than a smooth surface.

Answer (score 1):

Another option available to you is to do like I did on one kitchen remodel. I removed the range hood and carefully disassembled it removing the electrical connections, switches and light. I then sent the main metal part out to be chemically stripped. It came back looking all bare metal with most of the rust spots clean as well. In a few spots I had to do some additional work with steel wool remove any remaining corrosion. I then took it out to a paint and coating shop and had them put on a heat baked powder coat paint finish. The result was an amazingly good looking and durable finish.

I then reinstalled the electrical components and switches. If I recall correctly I took the opportunity to replace the vent fan motor with a new one to ensure a lengthy future life.