# Can I use flex duct for a range hood exhaust?

Tags: vent, ducts, microhood

I am replacing an old range hood with a hood/microwave/convection oven. The vent from the old hood does not line up with the vent position on the new unit. I know how to remove the old vent and patch the siding.

Installing the new vent is the problem. Just punching horizontally through the wall for the new vent won’t work. It would require cutting a vertical stud in a load bearing exterior wall (that was already cut and braced for the old vent). Cross bracing under the cut stud would be very difficult since there is an existing cabinet in place that limits access to the wall cavity.

I am thinking of using the top vent option on the hood unit, routing it up through the floor of the cabinet, transitioning to a round 6” duct adapter ant then horizontally through the wall to a 6” round wall vent.

[image: duct adapter] [image: wall vent]

There is just room for the round wall vent, to the side of the vertical stud. But because of an obstruction on the outside wall, there is not enough room to use a standard 90 degree elbow to the side (away from the stud) and then another 90 degree elbow toward the outside wall.

Can I use semi-rigid aluminum ducting (6” inches of course) in this kind of setup?

[image: flex duct]

Some of the ads for these products list range hood venting, but others do not. And some specifically say not to use for dryer venting.  What are the criteria for an acceptable flexible duct for range hood use? (I do know to avoid the filmy foil-over-spring type.)

**Note**: I know [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/72148/range-hood-with-an-offset) suggests that it can be done on it, but does not indicate which type of ducting is acceptable.

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/75097/33) might be useful.

Comment: The biggest issue is with it collecting grease. Fire? Far enough away? Replaceable?